# xenserver host lost all storage connections

Tags: storage, xenserver

I have inherited a xenserver setup running 6.0.  There is a storage pool set up with two host servers (a bad idea to start with I gather), 8 vms and several SRs.  I recently had one of the hosts fail and now it can't see any of the SRs that used to be attached, including the dvd-rom drive.  As a result, I cant restart any of the vms that were not on the HA plan (the HA protected vms are still running on the other host, fortunately).

When trying to reconnect the host to one of the SRs by doing a xe pbd-plug uuid=the_uuid_for_local_storage for example, I get the following error in response:

message: Failure("Storage_access failed with: INTERNAL_ERROR: [ Sm.Unknown_driver(\"lvm\") ]")

Attempts to plug the other SRs fail in the same way with the driver name varying depending on the type of storage.

A web search failed to bring up anything matching this particular error and the documentation hasn't revealed any clues either. Being new to xenserver, I'm a bit lost as to how to troubleshoot this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your server in the HCL ? Seem some hardware not recognized

Comment: It has been running for about 3 years without much trouble, from what I can gather.  It's an HP Proliant DL360 G7.  Twin to the one still running.  The root os seems to see all the hardware that's installed. It seems like something went wonky with the xenserver config, but I'd hate to have to rebuild the xenserver configuration from scratch and lose the data and vms residing on the local storage.

Comment: Double check at the official XenServer forums on the citrix site (GREAT people over there!). I was going to suggest attempting to export the VMs then rebuilding... but if the SR that the VMs are on won't replug either... hmm. Have any backups? I think you could use XenCenter -> Restore from Backup... but check the admin guide.

Comment: I have searched the forum @citrix without success, unfortunately.  Also unfortunate is the fact that the original admin didn't create a backup of this host.  There are snapshots of the VMs on shared storage though, so I think I'm going to bite the bullet and reinstall xenserver on the host and see if I can rebuild the VMs from the snapshots when I get the storage reattached.

Comment: FYI.  I managed to fix this by reinstalling xenserver on the broken host, telling the pool to 'forget' the host (effectively making it  stand-alone), then re-adding it to the pool.  The vm images were all still on the shared storage and came back up (pleasantly surprised at this).  I just had to reassign them to the host as their home server.  The broken storage issues went away when the old server instance was 'forgotten'.  Some local storage volumes were left hanging, but deleted without problems. All is well again.